# How to Access a Hierarchy Custom Setting from Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, customsetting

In Apex we can do

```
Hiearchy_Custom_Setting__c.getInstance().Field__c
```

In Visualforce we can do

```
$Setup.Hiearchy_Custom_Setting__c.Field__c
```

Is there any equivalent way to access easily from a Lightning component's helper.js?

I tried the following, which I'd think would work, but is returning "undefined" when it's definitely true:

Controller:

```
    public Boolean isBigDataMode {
      get {
          if (isBigDataMode == null) {
              isBigDataMode = Product_Pricing_Settings__c.getInstance().Use_Big_Data_Mode__c == true;
          }
          return isBigDataMode;
      }
      set;
    }
```

Component:

```
    <aura:attribute name="isBigDataMode" type="Boolean" default="{!isBigDataMode}"/>
```

Helper:

```
({
    getBigDataMode : function(component){
      console.log("big data: "+component.get("v.isBigDataMode"));
      return component.get("v.isBigDataMode");
    }
})
```

This is returning to the console

> big data: undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend the same as prashanthkr, this code should work:

JS Controller:

```
    var action = component.get("c.getHiearchySettings");

    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        if(component.isValid() && response !== null && response.getState() == 'SUCCESS'){
            //saving custom setting to attribute
            component.set("v.settings", response);
            console.debug(response.Use_Big_Data_Mode__c );//Check the output
            //... rest of your code
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Apex Controller:

```
public class MyController{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static MyHiearchy__c getHiearchySettings(){
        return MyHiearchy__c.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if the API changed, but I think it's supposed to be `response.getReturnValue().Use_Big_Data_Mode__c`

Comment: Instead of `component.set("v.settings", response);` I would recommend `component.set("v.settings", response.getReturnValue();`

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create an @AuraEnabled action method that returns the value of isBigDataMode to the component. You can find more details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_intro.htm)

Comment: Tried that, wasn't able to get it working.  Have a code snippet sample?