# Replacing hard coded messages inside Lightning JS controller

Tags: customsetting, customlabel, lightningjs

I have existing code which contains upto 20 hard coded messages(info, error etc.) inside my lightning JS controller.

I am confused whether to use custom labels or custom settings as part of code improvement.

I don't need any language translations in my project.

Can someone help me to provide the best practice to be followed in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have many hard coded messages at your component then better to use Custom Settings, as you can cache those messages. All the entries are stored as records as opposed to individual components like custom label.

Custom Labels are good if you have translations at your org and trying to remove hard coded values. Every label will be treated as separate components.

Accessing the Custom Label requires less coding and can be done on client side itself as follows:

```
$A.get("$Label.namespace.labelName")
```

Whereas to use Custom setting you need both client and server side coding. Refer [How to Access a Hierarchy Custom Setting from Lightning Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132177/how-to-access-a-hierarchy-custom-setting-from-lightning-component).

Answer (score -1):

I think the best thing to do is to created custom labels because custom settings needs to be queried.

Comment: While it is true that custom settings _can_ be queried, you don't _need_ to query for them. The `getInstance()` or `getAll()` methods (inside an `@auraenabled` apex method) would work.